# Failed to assume role for third-party AWS account using IAM user's access key

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sts-securitytokenservice, assume-role

I am trying to give a third-party AWS Account access to my AWS Account using Assume Role function with SecurityAudit role, similar to [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rf3jm3jEnPk&feature=emb_title). I followed the explanation from [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-user_externalid.html) to assign the third-party account the role called testing where I will get the trust relationship something like this (which I also added the IAM user of third party since it will access my AWS account using his access key):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::thirdparty:root"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Then I followed the code from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AuthUsingTempSessionTokenJava.html) as follow:

```
AWSSecurityTokenService stsClient = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard()
                                                    .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
                                                    .withRegion(clientRegion)
                                                    .build();

            // Obtain credentials for the IAM role. Note that you cannot assume the role of an AWS root account;
            // Amazon S3 will deny access. You must use credentials for an IAM user or an IAM role.
            AssumeRoleRequest roleRequest = new AssumeRoleRequest()
                                                    .withRoleArn(roleARN)
                                                    .withRoleSessionName(roleSessionName);
            AssumeRoleResult roleResponse = stsClient.assumeRole(roleRequest);
            Credentials sessionCredentials = roleResponse.getCredentials();
```

But when the third party run the code it received an error like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.AWSSecurityTokenServiceException: User: arn:aws:iam::thirdparty:user/TestOne is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::myaccount:role/testing(Service: AWSSecurityTokenService; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1632)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1304)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1058)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
    at com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.doInvoke(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.java:1307)
    at com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.invoke(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.java:1283)
    at com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.executeAssumeRole(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.java:466)
    at com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.assumeRole(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.java:442)
```

So if the third party AWS account want to do security audit to my account using his access key, how should it be correctly configured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error says that

```
arn:aws:iam::thirdparty:user/TestOne
```

is is **not able to assume** the role of interest.

In your question you correctly allowed the `arn:aws:iam::thirdparty:root` to assume the role. But this still is **not giving** `TestOne` IAM user permissions to do the same.

To fix that, the admin/root of the `thirdparty` account **must explicitly allow** IAM user `TestOne` to `sts:AssumeRole` in your account.

Thus the `thirdparty` account can add such permissions as **inline policy** to the `TestOne` user, for example. Obviously it can also be done using customer managed policies, or other IAM mechanisms. But inline policy seems as fastest and easiest to test.